# 時間の演算結果を元にした if 文の判定が、端末によって結果が異なる

Tags: python, python3

時間を演算して23400秒を超えているかどうかで処理を分岐させようとしています。
端末によっては、下のコードでelse側に分岐することがあるようなのですが、原因がわかりません。
バージョンはPython 3.9.7です。

```
syukkin_time = "08:30"
taikin_time = "15:00"
syukkin_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(syukkin_time,'%H:%M')
taikin_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(taikin_time,'%H:%M')
working_time = taikin_time - syukkin_time
working_time = working_time.total_seconds()

if working_time >= 23400.0:
  print('6時間30分以上だよ！')
else:
  print('6時間30分未満だよ！')
```

Comment: 「端末によっては」というのが判明していて再現性があるのなら、それらの間の差異の有無や発生条件と考えられるものの絞り込みを行って、結果を追記してみてください。そうした調査の過程で自分自身で見つけることもありうるでしょう。違いが発生した時の個々の変数の値をprint()で確認するのでも良いのでは？

Comment: elseの中で、それぞれの変数の値をprintしてみれば、どの値がおかしいのか、わかると思います。

Answer (score 0):

原因は分かりませんが, `syukkin_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(syukkin_time,'%H:%M')` だと, 日付(1900, 1, 1) が付きます。
環境によっては(例えばタイムゾーンなど), 時間の演算に支障をきたすことも。

文字列から秒に変換するのなら, 過去の質問にもあったはずなので調べてみるとよいでしょう

以下は pandas使う方法

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> t1 = pd.to_timedelta('08:30:00')
>>> t2 = pd.to_timedelta('15:00:00')
>>> t2 - t1
Timedelta('0 days 06:30:00')
>>> (t2-t1).seconds
23400
```